# Gradle custom builds

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with several modules with sources in different folders. I want to put the builds of those independent modules as tasks of the gradle build script.

```
/.
/abc/MyTest.java
/lib/<empty>
/build.gradle
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {  compile "javax.jms:jms:1.1" }

defaultTasks 'compileIt'

task compileIt (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = files("abc/MyTest.java")
    classpath = files("lib")
    destinationDir = file('classes')
}
```

MyTest.java:

```
package abc;       
public class MyTest {       
    public static void  main(String[] argv) throws javax.jms.JMSException {
        throw new javax.jms.JMSException("JMS test!");
    }    
}
```

Running gradle I got the following error:

```
C:\Develop\Java\....\MyTest.java:3: error:
package javax.jms does not exist
        public static void  main(String[] argv) throws javax.jms.JMSException
```

It seems the dependencies are not used whatsoever.

Putting "<<" into the task

```
task compileIt (type: JavaCompile) << {
```

I got:

```
C:\Develop\Java\.....>gradle
:compileIt UP-TO-DATE
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4.296 secs
```

but nothing is done so far...

Where is the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: The configuration of the `classpath` property is wrong. Why don't you use the `JavaCompile` tasks added by the `java` plugin? If you have multiple source trees, you can either declare multiple source sets, or use a multi-project build. Check the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the samples in the `gradle-all` download for more information on these concepts.

Comment: @Peter, I am working on a migration from very complex Ant script, and I cannot change the structure of the project, that's why I need to create more tasks for independent builds.
What is the correct setting of the `classpath` to get the dependencies from the definition? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the structure for that. If all you want is the declared compile dependencies, use `classpath = configurations.compile`. But there's likely a better way than declaring your own `JavaCompile` tasks. If you don't make use of abstractions such as source sets, other plugins won't "understand" your build, and you may not be able to (easily) use them. In other words, you don't generally don't want to end up with a Gradle build that's on the same (low) level of abstraction as the legacy Ant build.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is just the "workaround" I was looking for. But I will try to find a more elegant way to solve it. Then I will put it into the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to remove the usage of the java plugin and add the configuration for compile:

```
configurations {
    compile
}
```

then set up the `classpath` like this:

```
classpath = configurations.compile
```

Setting up `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` and `dependencyCacheDir` for the `compileIt` taks, it works as expected.

EDIT -------------------------

As discussed with @Peter Niederwieser, better is to customize the `java` plugin:

1. change configuration for the default build:

   ```
   sourceSets {
     main {
       java {
         srcDirs = ['abc']
       }
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

additionally you can change build directory:

```
    compileJava {
        destinationDir = file(project.get("build.binaries.dir"))
    }
```

2. add a new task for the second build

   ```
   sourceSets {
     ...
     compileTwo {
       java {
         srcDirs = ['abc2']
       }
     }
   }
   ...
   task compileTwo(type: JavaCompile) {
     source = sourceSets.compileTwo.allSource.srcDirs
     destinationDir = file('classes')    
     classpath = configurations.compile  
   }
   ```